How to get the sprite animation to run in debug mode in Godot 4.2.2
Godot Version 4.2.2
Hey new to Godot here,
The sprite animation runs in the editor mode, but the same animation does not run in the debug window. Could someone please help to figure out how to get the animation to run in Debugging mode.
Thankyou

Click on that A+ icons, set it to Autoplay on Load
And you can play different animations through code as well
        if velocity.x != 0:
            animated_sprite_2d.play("walk")
        else:
            animated_sprite_2d.play("idle")


